# Nfs-e pode ter mais de um serviço

Tags: xml

galera gostaria de saber o seguinte , estou tentando fazer um sistema de nota de serviço eletronica de bh . mas tenho uma duvida .

o xml pode conter dois serviços e dois valores do serviço e os valores somados na tag valor ?

se sim eu teria que repetir as tags responsavel por serviço e valores?

caso a resposta seja negativa é devido a ocorrencia ser  1-1

Comment: Não pode, no campo da descrição você discrimina quantos serviços quiser com o total dos mesmos.

Comment: entao a descrição pode ter varios escritos mas somente uma TAG. o xml e unico em cada nota certo ?

Comment: Isso mesmo, correto.

Comment: desculpa incomodar .

Comment: desculpa incomodar , a TAG < codigoTribbutacaoMunicipio > refere-se a que tipo de codigo . a que esta na tabela tributaçoes que e disponibilizada?

Comment: Terá que verificar no manual, diferentemente da `NFe/NFCe`, na `NFS` cada município tem uma documentação específica (obviamente existem municípios que adotam o mesmo padrão)